# Is it possible to use an Android (ARM) .so library on Linux-ARM?

Tags: android, linux, raspberry-pi, shared-libraries

I need to use a third-party's library in a raspberry pi (Linux ARM) project in order to communicate with their servers.

The only available libraries they provide are win32/64, linux_x86(32/64), iOS and Android (no libraries for static linking are provided).

I first tried compiling for linux_x86 (successfully) and emulating that executable under an emulator on raspberry pi (qemu) but failed to do so.

And just now I was wondering if the library for android would just work out of the gate on raspberry pi.
I don't think the library uses any android-specific features since it has the same functionality on all platforms.

So, is it possible to compile my program on raspberry pi (running arm-linux, such as raspbian) with Android's library?

Comment: Being an ARM processor doesn't implicitly mean same architecture.  But probably if you try, it will be the best way to test if possible.  Just in case the architectures are not compatible, you'll probably get an error message from the linker at link time.

Comment: @LuisColorado in my specific case, I've unzipped the libraries and found that the included libraries are simply not organised in the same way as the .cpp libraries since they're in Java and not c++, so sadly I wouldn't be able to use them. But I'm leaving the question up since it's more general than that specific case.

Comment: anyway and as an example of what I mean, ARM processors have an extension to execute Java bytecodes natively, It can be included in the Raspberry (don't know at this moment) and not in the Android processor you are using.  Working with binaries has these drawbacks.  I don't recommend you to use binaries as such... but you can be lucky! (who knows :) )